# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. I Want To save data from curl to database table

Tags: php, laravel, curl

> Api Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $statistics = Statistics::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($statistics, 201);
}
```

> route
> Route::get('statistics',[StatisticsController::class,'store']);

> CURL Function

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/kdk_local/statistics");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
       "game_id=3&user_id=3&bet=3&win=3&session_id=3");
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the route file make it `post` from `get`:

```php
Route::post('statistics', [StatisticsController::class,'store']);
```

> Use API route (`api.php`) for external API call.

Comment: I make the route to post but 419
PAGE EXPIRED this Error comes

Comment: updated my answer. you have to use API route (`api.php`) for external API call.

Comment: no I not use the api.php route ... I am using default (web.php) for the routes

Comment: so use `api.php` route

Comment: I can not under stand sir ...
i can make routes there api.php now it gives the error of method should be get

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

If don't work remove this file:

```
bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php
```

or

```
bootstrap/cache/routes.php
```